# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'new' error with django deployment using apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

Using versions:

**Centos 7**---**django 2.1.7**---**Apache 2.4.6**---**Python 3.6**

I get this error when trying to access the url of server:

```
 [wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=9020): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/user/project/new/wsgi.py'.
 [wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=9020): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/conner.johnson/ek/new/wsgi.py'.
 [wsgi:error] Traceback (most recent call last):
 [wsgi:error]   File "/home/user/project/new/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
 [wsgi:error]     application = get_wsgi_application()
 [wsgi:error]   File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
 [wsgi:error]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
 [wsgi:error]   File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
 [wsgi:error]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
 [wsgi:error]   File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
 [wsgi:error]     self._setup(name)
 [wsgi:error]   File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
 [wsgi:error]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
 [wsgi:error]   File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
 [wsgi:error]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
 [wsgi:error]   File "/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
 [wsgi:error]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 [wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
 [wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
 [wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 [wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 [wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
 [wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
 [wsgi:error]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 [wsgi:error] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'new'
```

my file structure(2 apps, but one app 'new' only houses the settings, wsgi.py, and the urls.py points to the second app)

```
─ home
    └── user
        └── project
            ├── app
            │   ├── <All Code for Webapp including static dir>  
            ├── env (virtualenv)
            ├── manage.py
            ├── new
            │   ├── settings.py
            │   ├── urls.py
            │   └── wsgi.py
            └── requirements.txt
```

My django.conf file seems to be in order but maybe not, i took out python-home since it didn't seem to do anything important

django.conf:

```
Alias /static /home/user/project/static
<Directory /home/user/project/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/project/new>
     <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
     </Files>
</Directory>


WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIDaemonProcess ek python-path=/home/user/project/new  
WSGIProcessGroup ek
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/project/new/wsgi.py
TimeOut 600
```

my wsgi.py (which i left untouched)

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'new.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I have tried adding this to wsgi.py

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/user/project')
sys.path.append('/home/user/project/new')
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything

I have also tried to add 'new' into the the settings.py under installed apps

The python path variable is correct and points to 'new' where wsgi.py is housed, and i don't think adding a python-home variable will do much.

I've searched around with other posts with this same answer and cannot find a fix for this, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should have `python-path=/home/user/project/` so that you can import `new`.

Comment: so take off `/new` at the end of python-path?

Comment: Yes, you want to be able to import `new.settings`, therefore you want the directory containing `new` to be on the python path.